# Convert a cross-distance matrix to a distance matrix

Tags: r, distance

I have a `crossdist` object `d` which I obtained using the package `proxy` as

```
# data is a data frame of 5000 rows and 5 columns
# Find dtw distance between rows in data

d <- proxy::dist(data, method = "dtw_basic", normalize = FALSE)

    str(d)
 'crossdist' num [1:5000, 1:5000] 0 3.72 6.38 2.66 3.43 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:5000] "11738" "1054" "9775" "13838" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:5000] "11738" "1054" "9775" "13838" ...
 - attr(*, "method")= chr "DTW_BASIC"
 - attr(*, "call")= language proxy::dist(x = df, method = "dtw_basic", normalize = FALSE)
```

I would like to convert it to a new object of class `dist` so that the new object must be like

```
str(d_new)
 'dist' Named num [1:...] 1.67 2.1 1.44 1.62 1.68 ...
```

Certainly, there is a function or an easy method to do this in R
but I can't find it although I searched a lot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Showing the output of `str` will not let anyone else other than you work with it.  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page on how to ask a question.  In particular show the output from `dput(X)` where X is your data or a suitably cut down version of it.  Also if this pertains to a particular package please name it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(dtwclust)
set.seed(5301)
x <- matrix(rnorm(500), ncol=5)
d <- proxy::dist(x, method="dtw_basic", normalize=FALSE)
class(d)
# [1] "crossdist"

d2 <- stats::as.dist(d)
class(d2)
# [1] "dist"
str(d2)
# 'dist' num [1:4950] 8.9 5.47 9.57 6.85 6.62 ...
# - attr(*, "Size")= int 100
# - attr(*, "call")= language as.dist.default(m = d)
# - attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
# - attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
```